# switch tab bar before navigation to another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am making an iOS app where I have ***Tab bar + Side Menu***.

*Tab bar have 5 items and side menu have around 12 menus.*

***All side menu functionalities are from Tab 1 & side menu is accessible across all views in tab bar.***

*That means if I am on Tab 2, even I can access side menu. When I click on side menu item from Tab 1, I will go to Tab 1 and then navigation will occur.*

*What I want to do is let's say if I click on Complains menu from side menu, I want to go to ComplainsViewController.*

***Code I used is as below.***

```
// go to first tab
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
// now navigate
ComplainsViewController *sViewCon = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Complains"];
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.5;
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:sViewCon animated:NO];
```

***I have two scenario.***

***Scenario 1 (Correct)***

*I am on Tab 1 and click on Complains from side menu. When I click, I go successfully to ComplainsViewController using above code.*

***Scenario 2 (In-Correct)***

*I am on Tab 2 and click on Complains from side menu. When I click, I go successfully to Tab 1, but I don't navigate to ComplainsViewController. When I click back to Tab 2, I see ComplainsViewController open in Tab 2.*

***Any idea how to switch first to Tab and then navigate to another viewcontroller?***

---

### Edit 1

Below is the basic structure I have.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried popping to root view controller before you push? `[[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Finally I managed to get it solved in another way with use of*** **`NSNotificationCenter`**

*Below is what I did.*

> Step 1 (In SideMenuViewController)

```
// let first go to first index
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0; 
// now post notification and make transition
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TakeMeToComplains" object:nil];
```

*Step 1, will change the selectedIndex and post the notification.*

> Step 2 (In all other view controllers)

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(globalTakeMeToComplains) name:@"TakeMeToComplains" object:nil];

 -(void)globalTakeMeToComplains {
      // here I have code for Transition to go to ComplainsViewController
 }
```

*In Step 2, when we switch to first tab bar, viewWillAppear get called where I am listening to the notification. Once I hear a notification, I will execute the transition to another view controller.*

***Do let me know if anyone is not clear on what I am doing.***

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you forgot to switch `navigationController` after switching tabs.
Try to implement `UITabBarControllerDelegate` method:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController * _Nonnull)tabBarController
 didSelectViewController:(UIViewController * _Nonnull)viewController {
    self.currentNavigationController = (UINavigationController *)viewController;
}
```

Then when you manually switch tabs use this code:

```
// go to first tab
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;

// Manually call delegate method
[self tabBarController:self.tabBarController didSelectViewController:self.tabBarController.selectedViewController];

// now navigate
ComplainsViewController *sViewCon = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Complains"];
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.5;
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
[self.currentNavigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
[self.currentNavigationController pushViewController:sViewCon animated:NO];
```

For this goal you will need create new property for keeping `currentNavigationController`.

Comment: ***Can you elaborate your statement*** *For this goal you will need create new property for keeping currentNavigationController.* **I  don't get what needs to be done...**

Comment: I was talking about creating property in class: `@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *currentNavigationController;`